# Link library to contract without migrations

Tags: truffle-migration, library

To link library in migrations I use:

```
await deployer.deploy(MyTokenL)
await deployer.link(MyTokenL, MyToken)
```

We want to use migrations as infrastructure deployment and then have a deployment factory nodejs for tokens that use the infrastructure. I read that migrations are not ideal for this factory approach because migrations are not intended to deploy the same token multiple times.

So I have the deployed MyTokenL and want to link it to a new contract deployed without migrations via:

```
//how link existing library, there is no deployer available???
const newlyDeployedToken = await MyToken.new()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the gold:

```
const linkContractWithLibrary = async (
  ContractArtifact,
  LibraryArtifact,
  libraryAddress
) => {
  const libraryName = LibraryArtifact.contractName;
  const libraryInstance = await LibraryArtifact.at(libraryAddress);

  //link function https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/blob/develop/contract.js#L564
  ContractArtifact.link(libraryName, libraryInstance.address);

  console.log("=> Used lib " + libraryName + ":" + libraryInstance.address);
};
```

Use it like this:

```
const MyToken = artifacts.require("MyToken.sol");
const MyTokenL = artifacts.require("MyTokenL.sol");

const myTokenLAddress = "0x4921e3822Ff02E0FbfEF1CB906b785484ccaf074";

//linking existing library
await linkContractWithLibrary(
  MyToken,
  MyTokenL,
  myTokenLAddress
);
```

artifacts.require() is also only available in tests but I guess you can load the abi as first parameter and do the same trick...

Comment: This solved my problem :D